# swig 2 marshaling to a std::vector<boost::filesystem::path> & from java to c++

Tags: java, c++, boost, stl, swig

Here is what I have:

```
%module FacadeInterface

%{
#include <Facade.h>
#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>
%}

%typemap(jni) boost::filesystem::path "jstring"
%typemap(jstype) boost::filesystem::path "java.io.File"
%typemap(jtype) boost::filesystem::path "String"
%typemap(javain) boost::filesystem::path "$javainput.toString()"
%typemap(in) boost::filesystem::path (boost::filesystem::path tmp) {
  const char *str = JCALL2(GetStringUTFChars, jenv, $input, 0);
  tmp = str;
  $1 = &tmp;
  JCALL2(ReleaseStringUTFChars, jenv, $input, str);
}

%include "Facade.h"

%include <std_vector.i>
%template(PathsVector) std::vector<boost::filesystem::path>;
```

Here is the contents of Facade.h

```
bool run(const std::vector<boost::filesystem::path> &plyFiles);
```

When compiling the java source I get the following error:

```
/root/build/src/main/com/facade/PathsVector.java:71: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to long
    return new SWIGTYPE_p_boost__filesystem__path(FacadeInterfaceJNI.PathsVector_get(swigCPtr, this, i), false);
```

Comment: What version of SWIG are you using? I can't reproduce this

Comment: @Flexo

```
root@7a4d7deb7b07:/home# swig -version

SWIG Version 2.0.12

Compiled with g++ [x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu]

Configured options: +pcre

Please see http://www.swig.org for reporting bugs and further information
```

Comment: Ah, interesting, I tested with several 3.x versions, might be worth you trying that if you can.